# Hiding DIV in ajax-loaded form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a modal that contains a dynamically generated form. It is being loaded via ajax call:

```
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href.indexOf('#') == 0) {
      $(href).modal('open');
    } else {
    $.get(href, function(data) {
      $('<div class="modal fade" id="modalR" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalR" aria-hidden="true">' + data + '</div>').modal();
    });
    }
  });
});
```

In this loaded form, I have a div that I need to hide/show based on a select form field. I have been using the following code, which works fine if it is already in the file. However, when I add this to the dynamically loaded modal form (it isn't always needed in the modal), it doesn't execute.

```
$(function() {
$('#location').hide();
  $("#type").change(function() {
    if (this.value == '12') {
        $('#location').show();
    } else {
        $('#location').hide();
    }
});
```

});

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because when the block is already in the file, jQuery detects it and binds the event. But when you load it via ajax, that's after the binding, so the new block will not have any events attached. So try to bind it after placing it on your page. I mean, something like this:

```
$.get(href, function(data) {
    $('<div class="modal fade" id="modalR" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalR" aria-hidden="true">' + data + '</div>').modal();

    $('#location').hide();
    $("#type").change(function() {
        if (this.value == '12') {
            $('#location').show();
        } else {
            $('#location').hide();
        }
    }); 

});
```

Comment: I don't think that works because the elements location and type don't exist until the ajax modal is called.